How can a Vuetify 3 app determine what the local currency is when the app is run?
I am working in Vue 3 and Vuetify 3.
I would like my app to use the local currency symbol based on wherever it is running. If the app is running in the US, I want it to use the dollar sign, if it is in Europe, I want it to use the euro sign, etc.

How can my app determine the locale?
How can my app determine the currency symbol for that locale?
How can I write my app so that all components that need to display a currency symbol display the local one?

I've never done and localization/internationalization with Vue/Vuetify though I did dabble with it from time to time in Java several years back. How is all this handled in Vue/Vuetify?

A given locale might use more than one currency, so there is no built-in method to derive a single currency symbol for a locale — for that you'll have to implement a mapping of locales to symbols that meets your project's requirements. (Asking for recommendations for such a third-party library is not on-topic for Stack Overflow — although you might find ISO 4217 to be a useful resource).
To resolve the default locale for a runtime using the Intl API, you can use new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale as demonstrated in this question.


const defaultLocale = new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;

console.log(defaultLocale);




Thank you, that worked very well and was particularly well-explained. I took the remark about not asking for a third-party library recommendation as a hint that an existing library to handle this kind of thing existed and found just such a library, which I have documented in my answer to the question. Thanks again for getting me pointed in the right direction!

The comment posted above by jsejcksn was very helpful and certainly got me the current locale. However, when I looked at the rest of the article for Intl, I found it unclear: it has methods that deal with things like currency codes but I can't make out whether they are to set it or get it.
I decided to do a search to see if any third-party libraries existed for this purpose and soon discovered the @dnvgl/i18n package on GitHub. I found the documentation very helpful in obtaining the current locale, country, currency code and currency symbol. It also enabled me to format money amounts appropriately for that locale. This will be very useful when my app is used in foreign countries.
Here's what I came up with:
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useTrackerStore } from '@/store/Tracker'
import { findIso4217CurrencyForIso3166Country, getCurrencySymbol, formatMoney, getSystemLocaleName } from '@dnvgl/i18n';
 
 const storeTracker = useTrackerStore()

 const myLocale = getSystemLocaleName()
 const myCountry = myLocale.substring(3)
 const myCurrencyCode = findIso4217CurrencyForIso3166Country(myCountry).alpha3Code
 const myCurrencySymbol = getCurrencySymbol(myCurrencyCode, myLocale)
 var myBalance = ref(formatMoney(storeTracker.getBalance, {precision: 2, currency: myCurrencyCode}))
    
</script>

By way of explanation, storeTracker.getBalance is a value obtained from a getter in a Pinia store which I want to display in my app. Each of the methods used from the i18n package is separately named in the import statement. I get the country code by parsing the locale with substring(); this approach may need to be refined for some of the more complex locale values. I'm also assuming that the country in question only uses a single currency, since that's what MOST countries do. My approach to getting the currency code would need to change if it was a country with multiple currencies. Lastly, I use formatMoney() to ensure that the money amount is shown with the appropriate currency symbol, thousands separator and number of decimal places.
